# Got an EX raid invitation for an inaccessible location. Is there anything I can do?

Tags: pokemon-go

I received an EX raid pass:

[image: EX raid Oct 1st]

However, the park will not open on October 1st, thereby making it impossible to participate. What can I do? Can the date be changed? Any other suggestions?

Comment: *[Comments Removed]* - I have generified the question to be about any inaccessible location rather than a specific location so it will be helpful to more people. This is an in-game problem for AR games like Pokemon Go and Ingress which rely on real-world locations to be accessible. We don't need to advocate illegal activities to answer this: The sane response is to either ignore the raid entirely or to contact Niantic and request it be moved to another date or location. Wondercricket's answer shows precedent that the latter is a viable solution.

Answer (score 7):

Since the gym is inaccessible during the time of the EX-Raid, your best bet is to [submit a ticket](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?ticket_form_id=911688&p=web&contact=1) with Niantic and explain the situation. According to the users on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/8yiobm/not_able_to_do_ex_raid_due_to_closed_park/), Niantic will cancel the raid and compensate you.

As evidence you will be compensated, a trainer I know received a few items after an EX-Raid they were invited to was canceled for unknown reasons just before the event.

[image: Compensation for canceled EX-Raid]

Answer (score 4):

All you can do is try to contact Niantic asking for an alternative raid or time, but, since the question is quite time sensitive, I doubt they will respond to your needs in time. I got a reply within two weeks when I contacted them on another issue.

Like in normal raids, you should not bother trying to get to a raid where the attendance of other players isn't expected to be high enough. After all you can't beat it alone.

Comment: I guess it is worth contacting them, at least for solving this issue for future raids

Answer (score 0):

Try submitting a [ticket to Niantic](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008306667-Submit-a-Request) explaining your particular situation. Friends in my community have received standard raid passes in return for EX Raids they have been unable to attend, though this is at Niantic's discretion.